# java - Exercise, do not work properly on the subject arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Check if the matrix is folded from.
The test should make:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DKEc.jpg)

The code always returns false and it is unclear to me why. What's wrong with the code?

the code:

```
public class test1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[][] mat = { { 1, 7, 9 }, { 2, 9, 7 }, { 9, 2, 1 } };

    boolean flag = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.length; j++) {
            System.out.print("[" + mat[i][j] + "]");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (int i = mat.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        for (int j = mat.length - 1; j > -1; j--) {

            if (i == j) {
                j--;
            }

            if (mat[i][j] != mat[j][i]) {
                flag = false;

                System.out.println("mat[i][j]" + mat[i][j] + " " + i + " "
                        + j);
                j = -1;
                i = -1;
            }

        }
    }

    if (flag == false) {
        System.out.println("Not first folded matrix");
    } else {
        System.out.println("First folded matrix");
    }

}
}
```

thank you

Comment: Well, let's see... The first time through the loop, what is the value of i and j? It's going to be i = 2, and j = 1. mat[2][1] is 2 and mat[1][2] is 9. These are unequal, and then you immediately set i and j to -1. At that point, your loop is done and will no longer execute.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Check if the matrix is symmetric with respect to its counterdiagonal?

Comment: I did not understand, can explain how to apply this code. How do I solve the problem

Comment: Do testing as outlined in the attached picture

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
public static boolean isFolded(int[][] mat){
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.length; j++) {

            if (i == j) {
                continue;
            }

            if (mat[i][j] != mat[mat.length - 1 - j][mat.length - 1 - i]) {

                System.out.println("mat[i][j] " + mat[i][j] + "  i:" + i + " j:"
                        + j);
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Call it in you `main` like:

```
flag = isFolded(mat);
```